# get list of same numbers by date difference

Tags: mysql, date-difference

I have mysql table with two columns  as below

```
number         date

1             2013-08-11

1             2013-08-15

1             2013-07-09

2             2013-08-18

3             2013-08-06

3             2013-08-21
```

Now I want all numbers for which date difference within 5 days for the same number.

Thanks all

Comment: So what's your expected result given your sample data?

Comment: Expected result is 1 as two dates for 1 ( 2013-08-11 and 2013-08-15 ) are with in 5 day duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT number
FROM   my_table a JOIN my_table b USING (number)
WHERE  b.date BETWEEN a.date AND a.date + INTERVAL 5 DAY
```

Comment: Sir it worked i just had to add a.date<>b.date as same record was also getting compared. Thanks a lot you saved a lot of work.